# arcpy buffer analysis how to use side type: exclude input polyon

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, buffer, arcpy

I need use a buffer around a polyline, I need to use the side type exclude the input polygon from buffer. I have tried a few ways of writing it but nothing has worked and there are no python 3 examples out there I can find. I tried no spaces, underscores for spaces, capitalizing the first letter with no space...help would be great!

sideType = "Exclude the input polygon from buffer"

arcpy.analysis.Buffer(IN_TABLE, OUT_NAME2, distance, sideType)

Comment: solved this by using a manual buffer in acrPro and saving the python script from the geoprocessing pane. Thanks to Vince for helping out in the GIS stacks.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443353/sidetype-exclude-the-input-polygon-from-buffer